# Are sojourn times independent in non homogeneous poisson process?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

We know that in homogeneous Poisson process, sojourn times are independent. But are they still independent if  $\lambda (t)$ varies? 
If so, what is the proof?
Thanks

the problem I have now is that after calculation, I am expecting f(s1,s2)=λ(s1)e^(-λ(s1))λ(s2)e^(-λ(s2)) if they are independent. But We I get is not this, the answer contains λ(s1+s2)! Please can any one help!

Comment: The book says "increments over disjoint intervals are independent random variables."

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "sojourn times"? The interarrival times?

Comment: @Math1000 Yes, the problem I have now is that after calculation, I am expecting f(s1,s2)=λ(s1)e^(-λ(s1))λ(s2)e^(-λ(s2)) if they are independent. But We I get is not this, the answer contains λ(s1+s2)! Please can any one help!

Comment: @YilinWang It would be helpful to include these thoughts in your question. As written it's not so clear what you're asking.